# python job on PowerShell not run

Tags: sql-server, powershell

i have a simple query which need to be run on Powershell of SQL Agent Job.
but when i run the job, the Step with Powershell doesn't run.
When i open a new powerShell window on my computer and run the Code, it worked.

i tried to created new Credential 'Win10' and use this Credential to run the job, but the Step with PowerShell still doesn't work. Does anybody have any Idea?
Thankyou

[image]

Comment: If you view the job history, does the log show any error messages?

Comment: did you tried to enter the full path of the python exe ; i.e. `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe` or whatever your python path is.

Comment: thankyou, i have tried it but it doesnt work. it get Error:  A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'python C:\JSON_IMPORT\code\import_coinmarketcap.py'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'Traceback (most recent call last):  '  A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'python C:\JSON_IMPORT\code\import_coinmarketcap.py'. Correct the script and reschedule